# Specify time after which popup should disappear using Leaflet Javascript library

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am using Leaflet Javascript library to make the interactive map.I am new to Leaflet and Javascript Is it possible using leaflet library to specify the time limit after which an idle(let say popup appeared on click to map and if no other interaction is performed with the map for 2 seconds) popup should disappear? If yes then how?

I am looking for something like this:

```
var latLanPopup = L.popup();
latLanPopup
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
    .disappear(2000)     // something for this line
    .openOn(map);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This completely depends on your definition of idle.

Comment: @iH8 edited question, explained ideal in my case.